# How Do I Escape The @ Character When Setting Up My Store-Uri In Spring Integration Email Receiving Adapter

Tags: java, spring-integration

I am configuring my email receiving channel using imapIdle, for my email account that has the character "@" in the password. I noticed that the code store-uri breaks because it is splitting the string based on the "@" character.

I read a comment by Gary Russel where he said that the character needs escaping. I have tried escaping the "@" character by typing "\@" but that did not work. The store-uri string is still getting split on the first "@" character. Hence I get

I tried replacing the "@" with its unicode representation "U+0040", but that did not work either

```
store-uri="imaps://${email.username}:${email.password.contains("@")}@outlook.office365.com"

08:38:24.536 WARN  [task-scheduler-1][org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter] error occurred in idle task
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: PASSWORDCHARACTERSAFTER"@"SYMBOL@imap.HOSTDOMAIN, 993; timeout -1
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:740) ~[javax.mail-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366) ~[javax.mail-api-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246) ~[javax.mail-api-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:195) ~[javax.mail-api-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.connectStoreIfNecessary(AbstractMailReceiver.java:332) ~[spring-integration-mail-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.openFolder(AbstractMailReceiver.java:339) ~[spring-integration-mail-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver.waitForNewMessages(ImapMailReceiver.java:170) ~[spring-integration-mail-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$IdleTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:289) [spring-integration-mail-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$ReceivingTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:254) [spring-integration-mail-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) [spring-context-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93) [spring-context-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_201]
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: J8t-d21@imap.sw730exda001.corpdev.visa.com
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:359) ~[javax.mail-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:217) ~[javax.mail-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:134) ~[javax.mail-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.<init>(IMAPProtocol.java:131) ~[javax.mail-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.newIMAPProtocol(IMAPStore.java:763) ~[javax.mail-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:698) ~[javax.mail-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    ... 17 more
08:38:24.544 WARN  [task-scheduler-1][org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter] Failed to execute IDLE task. Will attempt to resubmit in 10000 milliseconds.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure in 'idle' task. Will resubmit.
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$IdleTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:305) ~[spring-integration-mail-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$ReceivingTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:254) [spring-integration-mail-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) [spring-context-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93) [spring-context-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_201]
Caused by: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: J8t-d21@imap.sw730exda001.corpdev.visa.com, 993; timeout -1
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:740) ~[javax.mail-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366) ~[javax.mail-api-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246) ~[javax.mail-api-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:195) ~[javax.mail-api-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.connectStoreIfNecessary(AbstractMailReceiver.java:332) ~[spring-integration-mail-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.openFolder(AbstractMailReceiver.java:339) ~[spring-integration-mail-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver.waitForNewMessages(ImapMailReceiver.java:170) ~[spring-integration-mail-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$IdleTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:289) ~[spring-integration-mail-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: J8t-d21@imap.sw730exda001.corpdev.visa.com
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:359) ~[javax.mail-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:217) ~[javax.mail-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:134) ~[javax.mail-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.<init>(IMAPProtocol.java:131) ~[javax.mail-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.newIMAPProtocol(IMAPStore.java:763) ~[javax.mail-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:698) ~[javax.mail-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366) ~[javax.mail-api-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246) ~[javax.mail-api-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:195) ~[javax.mail-api-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.connectStoreIfNecessary(AbstractMailReceiver.java:332) ~[spring-integration-mail-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.openFolder(AbstractMailReceiver.java:339) ~[spring-integration-mail-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver.waitForNewMessages(ImapMailReceiver.java:170) ~[spring-integration-mail-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$IdleTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:289) ~[spring-integration-mail-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%40` - see [The HTML URL Encoding Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).

Comment: what if the password contains @?

Comment: That was the original question. See the answer.